# Unable to make file in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, make, gcc

I am trying to install a fluid simulation software (https://github.com/cwrowley/ibpm).
I have installed all the dependencies and was ready to execute the make command. Here is the error that I am getting from terminal.

```
(base) hell@hell-Precision-T1600:~/Desktop/temp/von_karman/ibpm-master/ibpm$ make
cd build && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hell/Desktop/temp/von_karman/ibpm-master/ibpm/build'
../config/make.inc:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hell/Desktop/temp/von_karman/ibpm-master/ibpm/build'
make: *** [Makefile:15: ibpm] Error 2
```

I also checked the Makefile in the parent directory. Here are the contents of the Makefile.

```
# Main makefile for IBPM code
#
# Clancy Rowley
# Princeton University
#
# $Date$
# $Revision$
# $Author$
# $HeadURL$

.PHONY: ibpm test doc clean distclean
DIRS = build test doc

ibpm:
    cd build && $(MAKE)

test:
    cd test && $(MAKE)

doc:
    cd doc && $(MAKE)

all: ibpm test doc

clean:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do ( cd $$dir && $(MAKE) clean; ) done

distclean: clean
    for dir in $(DIRS); do \
      ( cd $$dir && $(MAKE) distclean; )\
    done
```

I don't know which missing separator it is talking about.

The file make.inc links make.inc.gcc.
Here are the contents make.inc.gcc.

```
# standard config file, using gcc compiler

CXX = g++

# flags for compiling with optimization
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -Ofast -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG

# for debugging, uncomment the following line
# CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

# Specify directories for libraries and header files here
# lib_dirs = -L/path/to/lib

# include_dirs = -I/path/to/include
```

Also, when I execute `cat -A config/make.inc`, I get `make.inc.gcc`

Comment: Can't reproduce - the first line of `config/make.inc` (whichever ordinary file it links to) should be a comment - did you edit the file and remove the comment character `#` by any chance?

Comment: @Prakhar Sharma → cd ibpm/ && make : No errors. ( g++ version 10.3.0 ) ... ibpm depends on libfftw3.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have all dependencies installed. My g++ version is 9.3.0. I can't get new version even after running sudo apt get update.

Comment: @steeldriver I have changed anything. Also the first line of make.inc links the make.inc.gcc. Here are the contents of the file. # standard config file, using gcc compiler

CXX = g++

# flags for compiling with optimization
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -Ofast -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG

# for debugging, uncomment the following line
# CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

# Specify directories for libraries and header files here
# lib_dirs = -L/path/to/lib

# include_dirs = -I/path/to/include

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information - in fact, please add the output of `cat -A config/make.inc`

Comment: @steeldriver done

Comment: That's not how symbolic links should work - when you `cat` (or `cat -A`) `config/make.inc` you should see the *contents* of the file it links to, **not** the name of the file. I suggest you execute `ln -sf make.inc.gcc config/make.inc` and then try again.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes copying the contents of the file worked. I would notify the developer about this. Thanks a lot man. You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) actually worked. There is an error in the make.inc file. The `make` command should work once the file make.inc.gcc is linked to make.inc using the command `ln -sf make.inc.gcc config/make.inc`.